# How does enums types initializations in recursive functions work?

Tags: c++, c, enums

If I have an enum type declaration in a recursive function, will it be 'created' multiple times?

Does it work like '#define' in the sense that it just tells the pre-processor to 'swap' values (but with scope in mind)?
What would happen here, per example:

```
void recuFun() 
{
  enum someEnum {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT}; // Initialized multiple times?
  /* ... */
  recuFun();
}
```

I know that enum types aren't objects, and therefore won't be allocated to memory. but I'm not sure what's happening here, and as far as I know, it isn't a pre-processor 'swap' thing. it feels as if I'm wasting memory, or something like it.

Comment: Enumerations are nothing more than symbolic integer constants. With the code you show, using `DOWN` or `1` is just the same.

Comment: And please be careful, C and C++ are really two very different languages. Some things that might seem like they should be the same might actually be different. Plain enumerations are one of the borderline cases IIRC.

Comment: You know that types aren't objects and don't use any memory, but you still feel like you're wasting memory?

Comment: I don't think I expressed myself clearly. I didn't really know if it would have any impact whatsoever in the program during runtime besides the memory (which I knew that it certainly wouldn't have). That's what I meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `enum` doesn't really exist at the assembly/machine code level; it's all integral values there.

Declaring an `enum` or `typedef enum` in a recursive function will not use any more resources than declaring it in any other scope.

Comment: Indeed - it will not compile :)

Comment: @0___________ OP's code won't compile, but my answer is correct regardless

Answer (score 1):

```
void recuFun() 
{
  enum someEnum = {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT}; 
  /*...*/
  recuFun();
}
```

Does nothing as it has invalid syntax.

This one does nothing only defining enum type which does not affect the compiled code.

```
void recuFun() 
{
  enum someEnum {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT}; 
  /*...*/
  recuFun();
}
```

As it is defined inside the function (which is a gcc extension) the scope of this declaration is limited to this function scope.

Comment: Sorry, the '=' was a typo

Comment: Enums defined inside functions are a GCC extension? [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/fsYzr3j5Y) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/x45zof38q) both seem to have this extension too

Comment: Defining an enumeration inside a function is strictly conforming C, not a GCC extension. It has block scope, not function scope. The only identifiers with function scopes are label names.